# Creating a service that runs a python

Tags: raspberry-pi, services

I'm trying to start a service on a Pi4 by creating a .service file.

Here is my contents so far:

```
Unit]
Description=NZBHydra2 Daemon
Documentation=https://github.com/theotherp/nzbhydra2
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=something
Type=simple

# Set to the folder where you extracted the ZIP
WorkingDirectory=/opt/nzbhydra2

# NZBHydra stores its data in a "data" subfolder of its installation path
# To change that set the --datafolder parameter:
# --datafolder /path-to/datafolder
ExecStart=sudo -u pi /usr/bin/python /opt/nzbhydra2/nzbhydra2wrapper.py --nobrowser
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to run this as the user `pi` and not as `root`. I added the `-u pi` but I'm getting access denied to python. If I run it without the `-u`, it's creating files that only root has access too. The owner of /opt/nzbhydra2 is pi:pi.

How do I run this python script as the `pi` user and not as root but still have access to python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't (shouldn't) use `sudo` in systemd services or in any non-interactive script.  Instead, you can use the `User=` and `Group=` fields you've already discovered.

Your unit should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=NZBHydra2 Daemon
Documentation=https://github.com/theotherp/nzbhydra2
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/nzbhydra2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /opt/nzbhydra2/nzbhydra2wrapper.py --nobrowser
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```